# Data corruption - pyodbc to SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I have a Python script which is connecting to SQL server and fetching data from it. Everything works fine but sometimes the data gets corrupted. There is nothing on the terminal, no warning sign or error. And the data is perfectly fine in SQL server.

Snapshot of data at SQL Server.

[image]

Snapshot of data after it is read by Python.

[image]

Sample code

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

connStr = (
    r'Driver={ODBC Driver for SQL Server};'
    r'Server=ServerName;'
    r'database=DBName;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)

sqlQuery = pd.read_sql_query('''
    Select * from TableA
''', conn)

dfSQL = pd.DataFrame(sqlQuery)
```

I have absolutely no clue whats happening over here. Can someone please help.

@AlwaysLearning. Thank you for your comment. I'm pasting the snapshot over here as comments dont accept it. I ran the query in SQL server and can see errant bytes.
[image]

Comment: Assuming these are var/char or nvar/char columns, try using `cast` on the value containing `1003180506` as `varbinary(max)` to see if there are errant bytes on the end. The digit characters will be in the range of 0x30..0x39 (or 0x3000..x3900 for nvar/char), anything else present will likely be garbage such as whitespace or formatting control characters.

Comment: At the Sql Server side?

Comment: Yes, there are errant bytes. I just ran the query at SQL server. I cannot paste the snapshot over here. adding it in the post. Can you please tell me how to handle this.

Comment: You probably need to figure out how they got in there in the first place, e.g.: import of bad data files, encoding corruption between an app UI and the database, etc.. For this specific value with the `Â` character you could `replace(yourFieldName, N'Â', N'')` to remove it.

Comment: I dont have control over that. Is there a way to handle and correct fetch whenever corrupted data is encountered. Maybe convert everything into ascii and remove bad bits etc. I'm not an expert in Python, any lead would help.

Comment: Perhaps using an output converter in pyodbc will help? You could use it to manually check/clean the bytes returned.

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function